# Javascript length giving wrong result

Tags: javascript

I have got 10 elements under the array , when i am printing it , i am getting value as 7

```
var categoryArr =["Biryani", "Chips & Chocolates", "Gokul chat", "Ice creams", "KFC", "MCD", "Popcorn", "Snacks & Corn", "Soft Drinks", "Tea & Coffee"] ;


alert(categoryArr[0].length);
```

Please see this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/yLqjqmdh/

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with jquery, this is pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for the length of the first element inside the array instead of the length of the array, remove the `[0]`

```
alert(categoryArr.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the length of the first array element ("Biryani") if you want he length of the array you have to call

```
categoryArr.length
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
alert(categoryArr.length);
```

what you are doing is checking the length of first element(Biryani) of the array, which is actually 7

Answer (score 0):

`categoryArr.length` is 10

`categoryArr[0]` is `Biryani`

`categoryArr[0].length` is 7

Answer (score 0):

`categoryArr[0].length` will give you the length of first element i.e 7.
If you want to get total number of element inside array you need to do `categoryArr.length`, without the index.